# Docker "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server." after system reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7, iptables

I'm running a Docker MERN stack on CentOS 7 with WHM, CPanels and Apache, everything works fine until I reboot the server. I get the following error on the webpage:

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After searching around stackoverflow I found that if I run this command my problem is solved:

```
iptables -t filter -F
```

My question is, whats causing my problem? How do I configure my server so I don't need to run this command everytime my server reboots? Do I make a script to run this command everytime it restarts? Do I configure iptables?

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -t filter -F` command will clear all the rules from the filter table in iptables. This means that you will loose all the filtering rules from your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, I was dumb and forgot to open proper outbound ports, I only opened inbound ports.